# Error 1004 Can not run the macro. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Add-In installed in my Excel (which is stored in a separate folder) that I want to run in one of my Excel files through a VBA macro. Whenever I call the:

```
Application.Run "'Addintorun.xla'"
```

I get the error that the macro may not be available. I know I might need to enable all macros through Macro Security, but I can't tick this option since it's blocked by the administrator. However the add-in per se works fine, I just can't call it from the macro. I also added a reference to the Add-in in my module but nothing changed.

Comment: Not clear what you try doing. Irrelevant the add-in path... Do you want running  **from add-in** one of its existing `Sub`, or a `Sub` from another open excel file? Or viceversa, to run **from an open workbook** an adding `Sub`?

Comment: I want to run an existing add-in from another Sub I am writing, but the add-in wasn't written by me and when I try to access it from the VBA editor it asks for a password (I can't modify it). However, if I try to run the Add-in manually from the Add-In tab, it works fine.

Comment: Still not clear... I would say that you try referring to the second way. If so, you need to specify the macro name to be running: `Application.Run "Addintorun.xla!MyMacro"`. The simple quotes are necessary only if the name contains spaces. You can run a macro another workbook even using its `Full Name`, having the advantage that if it is not open, the calling way will open it. In such a case you may need the simple quotes (if spaces involved in the path)... But writing  `Application.Run "'Addintorun.xla'!MyMacro"` will also work.

Comment: Yes so I actually didn't specify the Macro to be run from the Add-In. Now i rewrote like: Application.Run "Addintorun.xla!MyMacro" but it still gives the same error. Do you know if this might be a general error with the two possible explanations: 1. I am not referring to the correct macro name(the add-in is protected by a password so i can't access it to see the correct macro name, I am inferring it) 2. I can't Enable all macros due to the option being disabled by the administrator

Comment: Does the respective `MyMacro` exist in a standard module of the add-in in discussion? If yes, make it public. Anyhow, if not `Private` it should run... Now, are you speaking about an **old add-in** made in the previous Excel versions? If not, please look of its extension! It should be `xlam`...

Comment: Ah yes it was private! I made it! Please add your as an asnwer so that I can mark it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish what you need:

1. Add the add-in as reference to the workbook you need calling its `Sub`s, `Function`(s). In this way you may call them exactly as in the add-in itself. Only in case of the same macro names, the add-in name must be used when make a call.
2. You can call the `Sub`s which are not private in the next way:

```
   Application.Run "'Addintorun.xla'!MyMacro"
```

The simple quotes are necessary only if the add-in name contains spaces, but it  is a good habit to use them all the time, since they do not bother a name without spaces, neither...

You can also obtain a result of a (not `Private`) function in the next way:

```
  Dim res As Long
  res = Application.Run("'Addintorun.xla'!MyFunction", 3, 9)
  Debug.Print res
  'MyFunction should receive two `Long` parameters and returning also a `Long`
  'It may return any kind of variable, but res must be declared to match it.
```

Such subs/functions can also be called using the **add-inn full name, instead of its name**. In this way, the add-in will be loaded/open during the call, if not already loaded...